# batch list all .xls files in folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I have following batch files to list all the excel files in my folder:

```
for /r %%i In (*.xls) DO echo %%i
```

However, this will also include all excel files in subfolders of my current folder. How can I prevent that? I only want the files in the folder itself, not the subfolder.

Comment: What's wrong with `dir *.xls`?

Comment: ok, I admit, I'm doing more with them than just listing them... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pff, silly question, silly answer: just remove the /r